# sql - Query to return duplicate rows with some differing entries

Tags: sql

My (simplified) database contains the fields: sys_id, date, time and reading. It also contains two different kinds of duplicate rows: those where all the fields are the same and those where different readings are recorded for the same date, time and sys_id. I can already create a query to find entries where every column is duplicated for the first kind. Could someone help me with a second query to identify only rows with identical sys_id, date and time but explicitly different readings?

Answer (score 0):

First get the distinct values you are interested in then a simple group by and having clause should work fine:

```
SELECT
    sys_id
    , date
    , time
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            sys_id
            , date
            , time
            ,reading
        FROM 
            TABLE
    ) as a
GROUP BY
    sys_id
    , date
    , time
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

the inner distinct query will combine duplicate lines with every value the same, the outer group by on sys_id,date and time will then only have multiple rows in the count if the reading were different.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a simple join

```
select * 
from table as a
inner join table as b on a.sys_id = b.sys_id and a.date = b.date and a.reading != b.reading
```